# Anaconda Launcher overriding my flask app run on local host?

Tags: python, flask, anaconda

I'm using Continuum Analytics' anaconda python package and am trying to run a flask app on my `localhost`. For some reason when I run my code and open 'localhost:5000', I see the anaconda launcher trying to load in my browser. It usually starts when I have recently used an IPython terminal. After a while it goes back to working the way it should, but I can't figure out why. The command prompt that's running the site gives the follow error when it gets a request.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2014 23:11:21] "GET /api/launcher_info/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

It's ovbiously routing the wrong way for some reason, but I have no idea why it would do that. Anyone have an idea what's happeneing?

Thanks

Comment: Okay, for some reason, when I open my localhost on Internet Explorer instead of Chrome it works correctly. After loading it in IE, a few more tries in Chrome gets it loading right there as well. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Anaconda launcher runs a flask app in localhost:5000 (or the next available port if 5000 is taken). You'll need to add some logic to use a different port if 5000 is taken, or start at a different port by default.